# What does "resume proper order" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Judge asks defendant Bobby Seale, who was gagged for misbehavoir in court:

> Judge: Let the record show that I tried, fairly and impartially. I
> tried to get the defendant to sit on his own. I ask you again, Mr.
> Seale, and you may indicate by raising your head up and down, or
> moving it from side to side, if I have your assurance that you will
> not do anything to disrupt this trial, if I allow you to **resume proper
> order**.

What does "resume proper order" mean?

Source: The Trial of the Chicago 7 (2020)

Comment: Return to his proper condition, i.e. have the gag taken off.

Comment: so order (or) condition are same?

Comment: _One_ of the many meanings of 'order' is 'a state in which everything is in its proper place'